# Can I speed up uniVocity CSV Parser?

Tags: java, csv, apache-drill, univocity

I'm working on a project that is using the uniVocity CSV parser to read an `InputStream` which contains CSV data.  Overall the CSV parser is working great, however there is one line which seems to be slow.

When I call the `beginParsing()` method, it seems to take almost 4 seconds just to execute this method in my unit test. Is there any way to speed this up?
Thanks!

```
this.csvSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
csvSettings.setLineSeparatorDetectionEnabled(true);
RowListProcessor rowProcessor = new RowListProcessor();
csvSettings.setProcessor(rowProcessor);
csvSettings.setMaxCharsPerColumn(ValueVector.MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
...
this.csvReader = new CsvParser(csvSettings);
logger.debug("Time to open CSV Parser: {} milliseconds", timer.elapsed().getNano() / 100000);

// This line is slow
csvReader.beginParsing(searchResults, "utf-8");
logger.debug("Time to open input stream: {} milliseconds", timer.elapsed().getNano() / 100000);
```

Here are the results:

```
19:35:23.475 [2112b444-e4af-cf7b-5006-7a79bbdae8dc:frag:0:0] DEBUG - Time to open CSV Parser: 262 milliseconds
19:35:24.912 [2112b444-e4af-cf7b-5006-7a79bbdae8dc:frag:0:0] DEBUG - Time to open input stream: 4634 milliseconds
19:35:24.921 [2112b444-e4af-cf7b-5006-7a79bbdae8dc:frag:0:0] DEBUG - Time to build schmea: 4727 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ValueVector.MAX_BUFFER_SIZE` is too large the process my have trouble allocating the required memory . For example, if it needs to start up with 2GB and the JVM is not initialized with enough ram (i.e. Xms < 2G) it will slow down because there's not enough memory available at startup.